# Meme Generator Problems

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have incorporated a meme generator within a website at:http://www.meetmckenziemason.com/meme.html. I am trying to do various things
1. I want to be able to add a share button that shares the meme after its generated to social media sites like Fb and Twitter
2. I want the font to stay the same on mobile devices in the meme generator where the user types up his or her meme. It looks different on mobile devices.
3. I also want to add text within the meme thats unchangeable ive uploaded a template

Here is the code which I used from https://codepen.io/ninivert/pen/BpLKRx

Code:

```js
// CAN\NVAS.js plugin
// ninivert, december 2016
(function (window, document) {
  /**
  * CAN\VAS Plugin - Adding line breaks to canvas
  * @arg {string} [str=Hello World] - text to be drawn
  * @arg {number} [x=0]             - top left x coordinate of the text
  * @arg {number} [y=textSize]      - top left y coordinate of the text
  * @arg {number} [w=canvasWidth]   - maximum width of drawn text
  * @arg {number} [lh=1]            - line height
  * @arg {number} [method=fill]     - text drawing method, if 'none', text will not be rendered
  */

 CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.drawBreakingText = function (str, x, y, w, lh, method) {
  // local variables and defaults
  var textSize = parseInt(this.font.replace(/\D/gi, ''));
  var textParts = [];
  var textPartsNo = 0;
  var words = [];
  var currLine = '';
  var testLine = '';
  str = str || '';
  x = x || 0;
  y = y || 0;
  w = w || this.canvas.width;
  lh = lh || 1;
  method = method || 'fill';

  // manual linebreaks
  textParts = str.split('\n');
  textPartsNo = textParts.length;

  // split the words of the parts
  for (var i = 0; i < textParts.length; i++) {
   words[i] = textParts[i].split(' ');
  }

  // now that we have extracted the words
  // we reset the textParts
  textParts = [];

  // calculate recommended line breaks
  // split between the words
  for (var i = 0; i < textPartsNo; i++) {

   // clear the testline for the next manually broken line
   currLine = '';

   for (var j = 0; j < words[i].length; j++) {
    testLine = currLine + words[i][j] + ' ';

    // check if the testLine is of good width
    if (this.measureText(testLine).width > w && j > 0) {
     textParts.push(currLine);
     currLine = words[i][j] + ' ';
    } else {
     currLine = testLine;
    }
   }
      // replace is to remove trailing whitespace
   textParts.push(currLine);
  }

  // render the text on the canvas
  for (var i = 0; i < textParts.length; i++) {
   if (method === 'fill') {
    this.fillText(textParts[i].replace(/((\s*\S+)*)\s*/, '$1'), x, y+(textSize*lh*i));
   } else if (method === 'stroke') {
    this.strokeText(textParts[i].replace(/((\s*\S+)*)\s*/, '$1'), x, y+(textSize*lh*i));
   } else if (method === 'none') {
        return {'textParts': textParts, 'textHeight': textSize*lh*textParts.length};
   } else {
        console.warn('drawBreakingText: ' + method + 'Text() does not exist');
    return false;
   }
  }

  return {'textParts': textParts, 'textHeight': textSize*lh*textParts.length};
 };
}) (window, document);





var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var canvasWrapper = document.getElementById('canvasWrapper');
canvasWrapper.appendChild(canvas);
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var padding = 15;
var textTop = 'i don\'t always make a meme';
var textBottom = 'but when i do, i use ninivert\'s generator';
var textSizeTop = 10;
var textSizeBottom = 10;
var image = document.createElement('img');





image.onload = function (ev) {
  // delete and recreate canvas do untaint it
  canvas.outerHTML = '';
  canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvasWrapper.appendChild(canvas);
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  document.getElementById('trueSize').click();
  document.getElementById('trueSize').click();
  
  draw();
};

document.getElementById('imgURL').oninput = function(ev) {
  image.src = this.value;
};

document.getElementById('imgFile').onchange = function(ev) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(ev) {
    image.src = reader.result;
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
};



document.getElementById('textTop').oninput = function(ev) {
  textTop = this.value;
  draw();
};

document.getElementById('textBottom').oninput = function(ev) {
  textBottom = this.value;
  draw();
};



document.getElementById('textSizeTop').oninput = function(ev) {
  textSizeTop = parseInt(this.value);
  draw();
  document.getElementById('textSizeTopOut').innerHTML = this.value;
};
document.getElementById('textSizeBottom').oninput = function(ev) {
  textSizeBottom = parseInt(this.value);
  draw();
  document.getElementById('textSizeBottomOut').innerHTML = this.value;
};



document.getElementById('trueSize').onchange = function(ev) {
  if (document.getElementById('trueSize').checked) {
    canvas.classList.remove('fullwidth');
  } else {
    canvas.classList.add('fullwidth');
  }
};



document.getElementById('export').onclick = function () {
    var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = 'My Meme';
    link.href = img;
    link.click();
  
    var win = window.open('', '_blank');
    win.document.write('<img style="box-shadow: 0 0 1em 0 dimgrey;" src="' + img + '"/>');
    win.document.write('<h1 style="font-family: Helvetica; font-weight: 300">Right Click > Save As<h1>');
    win.document.body.style.padding = '1em';
};





function style(font, size, align, base) {
  ctx.font = size + 'px ' + font;
  ctx.textAlign = align;
  ctx.textBaseline = base;
}

function draw() {
  // uppercase the text
  var top = textTop.toUpperCase();
  var bottom = textBottom.toUpperCase();
  
  // set appropriate canvas size
  canvas.width = image.width;
  canvas.height = image.height;
  
  // draw the image
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  // styles
  ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
  ctx.lineWidth = canvas.width*0.004;
  
  var _textSizeTop = textSizeTop/100*canvas.width;
  var _textSizeBottom = textSizeBottom/100*canvas.width;
  
  // draw top text
  style('Impact', _textSizeTop, 'center', 'bottom');
  ctx.drawBreakingText(top, canvas.width/2, _textSizeTop+padding, null, 1, 'fill');
  ctx.drawBreakingText(top, canvas.width/2, _textSizeTop+padding, null, 1, 'stroke');

  // draw bottom text
  style('Impact', _textSizeBottom, 'center', 'top');
  var height = ctx.drawBreakingText(bottom, 0, 0, null, 1, 'none').textHeight;
  console.log(ctx.drawBreakingText(bottom, 0, 0, null, 1, 'none'));
  ctx.drawBreakingText(bottom, canvas.width/2, canvas.height-padding-height, null, 1, 'fill');
  ctx.drawBreakingText(bottom, canvas.width/2, canvas.height-padding-height, null, 1, 'stroke');
}





image.src = 'https://imgflip.com/s/meme/The-Most-Interesting-Man-In-The-World.jpg';
document.getElementById('textSizeTop').value = textSizeTop;
document.getElementById('textSizeBottom').value = textSizeBottom;
document.getElementById('textSizeTopOut').innerHTML = textSizeTop;
document.getElementById('textSizeBottomOut').innerHTML = textSizeBottom;
```

```css
#meme {
  // border: 2px solid #333;
}

.fullwidth {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 800px;
}

#imgFile {
  display: none;
}

input[type='text'], input[type='range'] {
  width: 100%;
}

h3 > i.fa {
  margin-right: .2em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Meme Generator</h1>

<div class="box">
  <div>
    <div id="canvasWrapper">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  
  <div>
    <h3><i class="fa fa-picture-o fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>Source Image</h3>
    <div class="box">
      <div>
        <p>From URL</p>
        <input id="imgURL" class="block" type="text" placeholder="Link to image" />
        <a href="http://memeful.com/" target="_blank">Memeful.com</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>From Local Disk</p>
        <input id="imgFile" type="file" accept="image/*"/>
        <label for="imgFile" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-upload fa-fw"></i></label>
      </div>
    </div>


    
    <h3><i class="fa fa-commenting-o fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>Meme Text</h3>
    <div class="box">
      <div>
        <p>Top Text</p>
        <input id="textTop" type="text" class="block" placeholder="Top text" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Bottom Text</p>
        <input id="textBottom" type="text" class="block" placeholder="Bottom text" />
      </div>
    </div>

    
    
    <h3><i class="fa fa-text-height fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>Text Size</h3>
    <div class="box">
      <div>
        <p>Top Text: <span id="textSizeTopOut">10</span></p>
        <input id="textSizeTop" type="range" min="2" max="50" step="2" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Bottom Text: <span id="textSizeBottomOut">10</span></p>
        <input id="textSizeBottom" type="range" min="2" max="50" step="2" />
      </div>
    </div>

    
    
    <div class="box">
      <div>
        <h3><i class="fa fa-eye fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>Preview Size</h3>
        <input id="trueSize" type="checkbox"/>
        <label for="trueSize"><span>Show true size</span></label>
      </div>
      
      
      
      <div>
        <h3><i class="fa fa-download fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>Export</h3>
        <p>If the button doesn't work, right-click the image and save it</p>
        <p>If you are one mobile, download the source image and directly upload it</p>
        <button id="export">Export!</button>
      </div>

    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

[enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A//www.meetmckenziemason.com/meme.html"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i></a>
<a href="https://twitter.com/home?status=http%3A//www.meetmckenziemason.com/meme.html"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x"></i></a>
```

As CSS box is used making it user responsive, the font keeps adjusting depending on the user device.

Comment: So do I need to delete the div class box it still is showing a serif font on the mobile devices for the meme generator I just want it to dhow the same font as in the desktop

Comment: If you don't assign class box then you cannot make it user responsive. Try Manipulating the font by controlling it with another class